# glBufferSubData has peaks with small buffer sizes

Tags: c++, opengl

I am making a simple 2D game engine with OpenGL, and my `SpriteRenderer` class makes batches of sprites which use the same shader or texture. Once I sort them first by texture, then by shader, and then by depth, the `uploadData()` method of my `SpriteRenderer` class uploads the CPU generated vertex data to the GPU. For this I am using the orphaning method, which is said to be faster than a simple `glBufferData` call.

My problem is, when I have small numbers of sprites (<15), I have frames with huge stalls, but with numbers >20 up to 10 000 it runs smoothly. I wrapped opengl function into c++ classes. If I replace the `VertexBufferObject::uploadOrphaned()` method by the `VertexBufferObject::upload()` method, the stall goes away. Here is my vbo class:

```
    //vbo.h
    class VertexBufferObject
    {
    public:
        VertexBufferObject();
        VertexBufferObject(size_t allocSize);
        ~VertexBufferObject();

        inline ui32     id(){ return    (ui32)m_id; }

        template <class T>
        void    addData(const T& data)
        {
            const byte* convertedData = reinterpret_cast<const byte*>(&data);
            size_t size = sizeof(T);
            for (ui32 i = 0; i < size; i++)m_data.add(convertedData[i]);
        }

        void    initialize();

        void    resetData();
        void    upload(GLenum drawType);
        void    uploadOrphaned(GLenum drawType);

        inline  void    bind()  { ::glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_id); }
        inline  void    unbind(){ ::glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); }


    private:
        GLuint      m_id;
        //this is my custom dynamic array class, this is a hobby project
        //and I enjoy reinventing the wheel :)
        Array<byte> m_data;
```

and below is the cpp file:

```
    VertexBufferObject::VertexBufferObject() :m_id(0)
    {

    }

    VertexBufferObject::VertexBufferObject(size_t allocSize) : m_id(0), m_data(allocSize)
    {

    }

    VertexBufferObject::~VertexBufferObject()
    {
        if (m_id != 0) ::glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_id);
    }

    void    VertexBufferObject::initialize()
    {
        if (m_id == 0) ::glGenBuffers(1, &m_id);
    }

    void VertexBufferObject::upload(GLenum drawType)
    {
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_data.size(), &m_data[0], drawType);
    }

    void VertexBufferObject::uploadOrphaned(GLenum drawType)
    {
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_data.size() * 2, NULL, drawType);
        glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, m_data.size(), &m_data[0]);
    }


    void VertexBufferObject::resetData()
    {
        m_data.strip();
    }
```

I am learning opengl, so my VertexBufferObject class contains what I already know. I know there are other methods to upload data, but I want to understand the reason of the current problem with this simple method. I looked around forums including here, and nobody had a similar issue that I found of. Maybe my class has some errors?

Comment: "For this I am using the orphaning method, which is said to be faster than a simple `glBufferData` call." No, it isn't. The point of the orphaning is letting the GL know that you don't need the previous contents of the buffer any more. This is useful if you otherwise would try to overwrite the _same_ data storage by a call like `gl**Sub**BufferData`. What you are doing is _creating a new data storage_ for the buffer object in any case, and the sequence of `glBufferData(..., NULL); glBufferSubData(... the full range...)` is only a more complicated way to do `glBufferData(...the new data...)`.

Comment: that makes total sense, so the wiser way is to call glBufferData(...,NULL) only if the new buffer size is bigger than the older one, and then go with glBufferSubData. But still, I don't understand why would frames get stuck with fewer vertices? Shouldn't going glBufferData(...,NULL) then glBufferSubData() get the same performance with glBufferData(full range) ?

Comment: I can't help you with your actual issue. I was just giving a side-note about the orphaning. The point is that using a sequence BufferSubData, draw, BufferSubData, draw, ... is sub-optimal because the GL works asynchronously, and when overwriting the buffer the second time, it might not be finished with the previous draw which depends on the current contents of the buffer, so it has to wait. Orphaning does help by allowing it to use a different storage (and destroy the old one after it is done with the draw). Note that it doesn't matter if this all happens in one or several frames.